# AngularJS - Dynamic name based on drop down result

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I've got a small issue which I'm hoping someone can resolve. It's straightforward if I wanted to take the ID but, unfortunately, I need another piece of information. I have labels for each of my drop-down lists and for one of these I would like to make it dynamic. So, you would select a value from the drop-down list and then whatever you have selected it would be the name for another list.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWDQA.png)

Now I need to use the ID to store the information, so I can't simply just set the name of it since the ID is used instead. As shown in the code, I first tried the {{targetEntity.user}} as a means to make it dynamic, but alas it wasn't the name. I was wondering if there I could still get the name from creating another variable

AngularJS (Code to call the values):

```
  $scope.userList = [{}]
    SpringDataRestService.get(
        {"collection": "users"},
        function (response) {                   // Success Function
            var user= response._embedded.users;
            for (var i = 0, len = user.length; i < len; i++) {
                var newUser = {id: user[i].id, name: user[i].name};
                $scope.userList .push(newUser );
            }
        },
        function (response) {                   // Failure Function
            $scope.alerts.push(new DentAlert(AlertType.ERROR, generateAlertMessage(response)));
        }

    );
    $scope.targetEntity.user= $scope.userList [0].id;
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user"
                               class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 control-label no-padding-right">User:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                            <select theme="bootstrap"
                                    ng-options="user.id as user.name for service in userList"
                                    id="user"
                                    ng-model="targetEntity.user"
                                    class="form-control">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <label for="dynamicLabel"
                               class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 control-label no-padding-right">{{targetEntity.user}}</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                            <select theme="bootstrap"
                                    id="userGroup"
                                    ng-options="userGroup.name as userGroup.name for userGroup in idList"
                                    ng-model="targetEntity.userGroup"
                                    class="form-control">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Sorry if my explanation isn't clear enough, I hope I provided enough details but you need more help, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking  for

```js
var app = angular
  .module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myController", function($scope) {
 $scope.names = ["Data", "All users", "X","Y"];
                    
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Machine Test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    Normla Drop Down
    <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br> {{selectedName}}
    <select ng-model="selectedData" ng-if="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
    </select>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```